# I am getting, Python Syntax error and can not find it

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the lucky numbers from 0 to 10 but getting syntax error says on line 13, which is `while` line. I can not find it.

```
from sys import stderr
from time import process_time
from typing import Dict, List


def calculate_possibilities(max: int) -> Dict[int, int]:
    """Calculate the numbers of lucky numbers from 0 to 10**(max - 1)"""
    possibilities: Dict[int, int] = { 0: 0, 1: 2 }
    index: int = 2
    while index < max:
        possibilities[index] = 2 * (9 ** (index - 1)) + 8 * possibilities[index - 1]                           
        index += 1
    return possibilities
```

Comment: difficult to tell due to the invalid indentation.

Comment: what type of syntax error? IndentationError? And on which line? Need more info.

Comment: @AbhijithShivaswamy I am getting 'unexpected indent'

Comment: In that case, you have indentation issues :) You need to correct it.

Comment: haha edit suggested for 'deleting my thank you for all help' line. Is that a joke?

Comment: @m.alban Download python-lint - https://www.pylint.org/#install.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I assumed the issue was your type-hinting, however I've fixed the indentation via an edit to your question and that code should work as required.

Comment: Newer versions of Python have the ability to add type hints. That line is fine.

Comment: My code was looking like the one you suggested anyway, so I did not get the point of your answer. You wrote exactly same.

Comment: I've edited your code sample in your answer, as you mentioned you had an indentation error. If you're still getting an error after running the edited code be sure to include the full error by editing your question and I can edit this answer as needed.

Comment: You mean that you edited by removing 'thank you' message? Ahh you removed spaces... @Shayn